# Sorting TreeView nodes by comparing theire Tag properties

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

I wrote a comparator and I want to implement it on parent nodes of a `TreeView` but what I need to be compared is the `Node.Tag.ToString()` and not by theire `Text`. As far as I looked there is no overload or another function to do this using `TreeView.Sort()`.

I wonder if you have a way or workaround in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an IComparer, it looks like you can set the [TreeViewNodeSorter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter.aspx) property to it and then call Sort to have the nodes sorted as you wish.

Example based on that link - not tried, no null checks etc. but it should work:

```
public class NodeSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TreeNode tx = x as TreeNode;
        TreeNode ty = y as TreeNode;
        return string.Compare(tx.Tag.ToString(), ty.Tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then `treeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = new NodeSorter();` somewhere in your setup.

Comment: Yeah but I beleive this sort the nodes based on theire `Text` not the `Tag`

Comment: @Sean87: If you look at the `public class NodeSorter` in the example towards the bottom of that link, the objects passed to the `IComparer` are the `TreeNode`s themselves rather than just the text. The example still uses the `Text` property (sorting by length rather than content) but I don't see any reason you shouldn't use the `Tag` property. I might edit in an example.

Comment: You are right! I was passing the text of nodes! how pathetic! Thanks a lot!